# Displaying an attributed string in a CATextLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple example app where I create a `CATextLayer` and set its `string` property to an `NSAttributedString`. I then add that CATextLayer to a view.

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CTFontRef fontFace = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)(@"HelfaSemiBold"), 24.0, NULL);
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [attributes setObject:(__bridge id)fontFace forKey:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem Ipsum" attributes:attributes];

    CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100);
    textLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    textLayer.string = attrStr;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
}
```

This works great in the simulator except the text is black instead of blue. When running on a device everything displays like it does on the simulator but it generates the following two errors in the console.

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
```

Should I be setting a CGContext somewhere? Am I setting my attributes wrong? Am I completely on the wrong track. Note, this for an iOS 5.x app and I want to use a `CATextLayer` for performance reasons. The real app is going to have **many** `CATextLayer`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use `CGColor` instead of `UIColor` for `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`:

```
[attributes setObject:(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor
               forKey:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

Comment: I *always* forget to use .CGColor when working at the CoreGraphics level. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I converted this to Swift 3 and put it inside SpriteKit as well:

```
import QuartzCore
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  var textLayer = CATextLayer()

  func helloWord() {
    let fontFace = CTFontCreateWithName((("HelfaSemiBold") as CFString),
                                        24.0,
                                        nil)
    var attributes: [AnyHashable: Any]? = [:]
    attributes?[(kCTFontAttributeName as String)] = fontFace
    attributes?[(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String)] = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello Attributed Word!",
                                     attributes: attributes as! [String : Any]?)

    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(50), y: CGFloat(200),
                             width: CGFloat(300), height: CGFloat(100))
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    textLayer.string = attrStr
    self.view?.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    helloWord()
  }
}
```