# How can I make my text from "drawInRect" above the gradient layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a new class named `MySegment` which inherits from `UIControl`.

First, I initialized a gradient line with `CAGradientLayer`.

Second,`[self.layer addSublayer:myLayer]`

Then, `["myString" drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes]` is in the same location.

I want the text from `drawInRect` to be overlaid on `myLayer`, but no matter what I use `addSublayer` or `insertlayer`，my text is always under `mylayer`, the effect is shown on the photo.

How can I make my text above the gradient layer?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a `CATextLayer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd indeed use `CATextLayer` as @DonMag has pointed out. In that case, you would have `CATextLayer` and `CAGradientLayer`.

First insert the `CAGradientLayer` using `addSubLayer`

`[self.layer addSubLayer:gradientLayer];`

Then the `CATextLayer` using `insertSubLayer:above:`

`[self.layer insertSubLayer:textLayer above:gradientLayer];`

PS: Answered question about putting attributedstring in CATextLayer:
[Displaying an attributed string in a CATextLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052863/displaying-an-attributed-string-in-a-catextlayer)